# AWS S3 CLI - Download versioned files & folders from bucket that had been uploaded before a specific date

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We're looking into if it's possible to bulk download files from S3 from before a specific date.

Let's say we want to download all files that had been uploaded before 10th Feb 2020.

The caveat being that it should download the *version* of the file at that time. e.g.

If we have a versioned file called "cat.jpg" one uploaded on 8th Feb, and one uploaded on 15th Feb, we would expect to have downloaded the copy from 8th of Feb.

Is this possible from the `CLI`, and if so, where would we start?

P.S. would ideally want to do this at `directory` level e.g. `public_html/uploads`

Thanks

Comment: No, that is not possible out of the box. You will probably need a [`list-object-versions`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/list-object-versions.html) and then filter the result and operate on that and then download the files individually. Bulk downloads are nothing S3 supports at all.

Comment: You best bet is to use S3 inventory to get a report, filter it using Athena based on `LastModifiedDate` and feed the result to a custom script to do the download.